# Is it possible to show two different dialog window in one window on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, widget

I have a different dialog windows in my qt project. But in some case i want to show two different windows on one page. I know the widgets are able to do that. But i do not know how can i implement this.

Is anybody know or can give me a example about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use QMdiArea [QMdiArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html) [exemple here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-mdi-example.html)

Comment: post the relevant code here, so users don't need to follow the link (which may broke eventually)